# How to solve this deadlock?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, deadlock

I have an UWP application in which I am trying to store and retrieve some data from a local text file but no matter how I try to do it the application gets deadlocked. Due to synchronous stuff that needs to happen, I try to use a task and wait for its completion but nevertheless, the application locks.

I have a page in my UWP application called "MainPage" and in it's constructor I have the following code:

```
var listenkeyViewModel = new ListenkeyViewModel();
listenkeyViewModel.GetKey();
listenkey = listenkeyViewModel.Listenkey;
```

The get key is the issue here because it calls a method on the ViewModel (which I created to be synchronous because I thought making the call synchronous asap would be preferable.

```
public void GetKey()
{
    try
    {
        var listenKeyTask = RetrieveListenKey();
        _listenkey = listenKeyTask.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}

public static async Task<string> RetrieveListenKey()
{
    try
    {
        var storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var listenkeyFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("listenkey.txt");
        return await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(listenkeyFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not load file");
    }
}
```

I know the thing is "async all the way down" but this is not possible here. I cannot make the constructor where the original code lies asynchronous. How are you supposed to not get deadlocked? I do not understand.

Comment: Move the code away from the constructor. Put in in an async method like 'InitializeAsync' or whatever. It is the best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `GetKey` to async/await

```
public async Task GetKey() {
    try {
        var listenKeyTask = RetrieveListenKey();
        _listenkey = await listenKeyTask;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //...should handle/log error
    }
}
```

Move the calling of this out of the constructor and into an event handler. like page load or some other event called early in the lifecycle of the page.

```
partial class MainPage : Page {
    ListenkeyViewModel listenkeyViewModel;
    string listenkey;

    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        listenkeyViewModel = new ListenkeyViewModel();
        // add a handler to be called when the page has been loaded
        this.Loaded += OnPageLoaded;             
    }

    async void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {            
        await listenkeyViewModel.GetKey();
        listenkey = listenkeyViewModel.Listenkey;
    }

    // Shown for demonstration purposes only.
    // This is typically autogenerated by Visual Studio.
    private void InitializeComponent() {
    }
}
```

`async void` is allowed on event handlers so this should allow the process to flow without deadlock.